# HTML pages mapping not found in spring mvc viewResolver

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

When I try to return .html view from spring controller I am getting "mapping not found", but if I change the extension of my html page into .jsp, spring is able to find the file.

spring config:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value> 
    </property>

    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.html</value> 
    </property>
  </bean>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public ModelAndView test() {
        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }
```

The view page location is correct since when I make it .jsp, it starts working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a "/WEB-INF/views/home.html" file or just a "/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp"?

Comment: if I am asking for .jsp, I am making that as .jsp, otherwise .html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view resolver configuration will take the view name `home` from `return new ModelAndView("home");`, add will look for an file that name/directory is builded by adding `/WEB-INF/views/` and `.html` to the view name: in the example it will be: `/WEB-INF/views/home.html`.

If this file does not exist, you will get an exception. If you want to have an jsp, then put hat jsp in `/WEB-INF/views/` and change the view resolver postfix from `.html` to `.jsp`

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value> 
    </property>

    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value> 
    </property>
  </bean>
```